# transform module path in webpack

Tags: webpack, karma-runner

I'm using karma@1.5.0 and webpack@1.8.4

I want to pull in a source file to a test. This source file has an external dependency though that is resolved in a different environment that is not running during the tests.

The external dependency in the file I want to import looks like this:

```
import MyModule from 'external!myFile';
```

In my test environment, external means nothing. 
I basically want to replace 'external!myFile'
with
'../../foo/bar/myFileLocal'

I've tried a few different things, the simplest is an npm package
"string-replace"

My webpack configuration is exclusively contained within my karma config:

```
webpack: {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
      {
        test: /srcFileName\.js$/,
        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
        query: {
          search: 'external!myFile',
          replace: '../../testlibs/myFile',
          strict: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  watch: true
},
```

The replace isn't happening when webpack compiles the sources and I just get the error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'external' in (my abs path 
edited)\js\models
 @ ./js/models/myFile.js 9:31-67
```

I tried some other approaches using a custom loader, but I still need to map the file path after 'external!'

Anything obvious I'm missing?
Thanks

Update: I've edited the test property regex from "myFile" to "srcFileName" to clarify, still have same problem.

Update: My regex was off. File name was srcFileName1. Changing the test to `/srcFileName1\.js$/` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule that replaces the `external!myFile` import does not apply to the file you're importing it in, but to the actual `myFile.js`. The regex should match the file that contains the import:

```
{
  test: /fileThatContainsImport\.js$/,
  loader: 'string-replace-loader',
  query: {
    search: 'external!myFile',
    replace: '../../testlibs/myFile',
    strict: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. Naming the test file as "myFile" was confusing. 

I updated the original question to show the test as
    `test: /srcFileName\.js$/`
But I still have the same error.

Comment: Actually, my regex was off. The file name was srcFileName1.js,  but my test was srcFileName. I updated my regex and it works. Your comment  helped me get it working, so I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks for commenting.